# Py.Test Can't find pytest-parallel when invoked programmatically

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytest, pytest-parallel

I am trying to send *parallel* arguments by a programmatic invocation to **pytest** but doesn't seem to recognize them like when *parallel* is not installed at all, except that I know is there because when I run **py.test** with a direct command line invocation including the same arguments, it will find it and run successfully.

> ERROR: usage: invoke_pytest.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
>   invoke_pytest.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --workers 1 --tests-per-worker 4

This is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import pytest


pytest_args = [
    "tests/bdd",
    '--rootdir=tests/bdd',
    "--workers 1",
    "--tests-per-worker 4"
    # ...
]
result = pytest.main(pytest_args)
print(f"RESULT {result}")
```

Although it seems unrelated, I am also using py.test bdd and splinter for this test suite.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out it is the way **py.test** parse arguments programmatically and has nothing to do with parallel. The values of each argument need to be an independent position of the list!

```py
# ...
pytest_args = [
    "tests/bdd",
    '--rootdir=tests/bdd',
    "--workers", "1",
    "--tests-per-worker", "4", # splitted argument and value
    # ...
]
result = pytest.main(pytest_args)
print(f"RESULT {result}")
```